# How to write use-case-scenario without having real actors?

Tags: uml

I have some difficulties defining actors in my following example, when I try to make a use case scenario.

The specification is:

There is a system_a depending on another system_b.
Whenever system_a is active, system_b outputs "true"

So my current use-case-scenario is:

```
use case: outputting "true"
system: system_b
actor: system_a (?)

 - 1. system_b recognizes activation of system_a
 - 2. system_b outputs true.
 - 3. use-case-scenario succeeded.

  - 1a. system_b recognizes deactivation of system_a
  - 1a1. use-case-scenario failed.
```

is this use-case-scenario alright?

Answer (score 1):

A use case without actor is no use case. When I do someone a favor an say "de nada" it's not "for nobody" but "for nothing". A use case is always towards someone or something gaining added value.

So when you say `system_b outputs "true"` there needs to be an actor reading that value. If there were nobody to read it, it would be a useless case.

Answer (score 0):

A use case is meant to describe the behavior of a particular system, called the subject. The primary actor is the person who (or the system which) is using the subject. There may be secondary actors, who (or which) are used by the subject.

In your case, the primary actor is the human or the system that is using system_b. In other words, the primary actor is where system_b sends its output to. You may regard system_a as the secondary actor.